# For loop not working with string.length in Ruby irb

Tags: ruby, irb

In irb, bash shell, on a mac. As you can see, a is a defined array. Putting a.length in parens makes no difference.  The output should be the array, but no output appears.

```
>> a
=> ["ant", "bat", "cat", "42"]
?> for i in 0..a.length do
?>       puts a[i]
>> end
?>
```

The loop is an exercise in this tutorial: [link](https://www.learnenough.com/course/ruby/arrays/array_iteration) but it is behind a paywall. In the text it looks like this:

```
Listing 3.3: Combining array access and a for loop.

>> for i in 0..a.length do
?>   puts a[i]
>> end
ant
bat
cat
42
```

I assume that a.length is the problem because the following works:

```
?> for i in 0..3 do
?>     puts a[i]
>> end
ant
bat
cat
42

=> 0..4
```

What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: What output is your initial attempt giving? Any errors?

Comment: How are u creating/initializing `a` ? I tried this same thing by doing `a = ["ant", "bat", "cat", "42"]` and then the loop and it works

Comment: The issue is the loop-style `do` which apparently is interpreted as block-style `do` so irb is incorrectly waiting for an additional `end`. Definitively a bug! The `do` here (or `then`) is often unnecessary anyway.

Comment: I pasted the code in your question and it worked. You should use `...` not `..` to keep your iteration in-bounds though

Comment: @OmneBonum : While this is a somewhat unusual way to iterate an array in Ruby, I get exactly the output you expected.  The only way that your code does not give an output, would be if `a` is an empty array, but you have demonstrated that it is not empty.

Comment: @SagarPandya the output is exactly what you see in the first block of code above: ?> followed by eternal emptiness.

Comment: @leoOrion I know it seems like it would have to be how the array is initialized, but, alas, the puts command works fine outputting the array.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

@Cremno wins the kewpie doll.  Not even the helpful code @benjessop provided worked until I omitted the 'do' from each of them.  Then, everything works as it should, including my original example.

So, solution: Simply remove the 'do'

To be clear, the 'do' works if the range is 0..3 (or, I assume, any numerical range) but once I replace the 3 with a variable len or a.length, including the 'do' means that after the 'end', ?> appears, followed by nothing. Typing 'end' again does no good.  I have to ^C out of the loop.

Comment: This failure to loop because of combing a variable in a range and a 'do' seems to be something that is only happening to me on my system.  If it is, as @Cremno suggests, a bug, how do I fix it?